# How do I boot a bootable .bin file from a CD/DVD?

Tags: boot, boot-loader, binary

I have written a bootable program in assembly and compiled it into an .bin file.
I want to make it boot from a CD/DVD.
How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Very briefly (I'll leave it to others with more time to write a step-by-step answer):

You need to create an ISO9660 filesystem with an [El Torito](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_Torito_(CD-ROM_standard)) boot extension. This more or less embeds a complete floppy disk image into the filesystem.

So first you must convert your bootable program into a form where it would boot from a floppy (write it into the boot block, use BIOS calls to read the other blocks if necessary). Then you add this floppy image to the ISO filesystem with the `-b` option of `mkisofs`.

There are variants of this where you pretend to have a harddisk instead of a floppy disk on the CD.